# JQuery CSS Transform Working in Chrome and Firefox but Not IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a pointer image under some tabs that moves towards the respective tab when clicked. This works in Chrome and Firefox, but it doesn't work in IE.

The fiddle is here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hLkkzbqq/1/)

The code is below in which:

Tab 1 id=1

Tab 2 id=2

Tab 3 id=3

```
$('#1').click(function(){
$('#triangle-tab').css({
    '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(-330px)',
    '-moz-transform' : 'translateX(-330px)',
    '-ms-transform' : 'translateX(-330px)',
    'transform' : 'translateX(-330px)',
    '-webkit-transition-duration' : '.5s',
    '-moz-transition-duration' : '.5s',
    '-ms-transition-duration' : '.5s',
    'transition-duration' : '.5s'
});
});

$('#2').click(function(){
$('#triangle-tab').css({
    '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(0px)',
    '-moz-transform' : 'translateX(0px)',
    '-ms-transform' : 'translateX(0px)',
    'transform' : 'translateX(0px)',
    '-webkit-transition-duration' : '.5s',
    '-moz-transition-duration' : '.5s',
    '-ms-transition-duration' : '.5s',
    'transition-duration' : '.5s'
});
});

$('#3').click(function(){
$('#triangle-tab').css({
    '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(330px)',
    '-moz-transform' : 'translateX(330px)',
    '-ms-transform' : 'translateX(330px)',
    'transform' : 'translateX(330px)',
    '-webkit-transition-duration' : '.5s',
    '-moz-transition-duration' : '.5s',
    '-ms-transition-duration' : '.5s',
    'transition-duration' : '.5s'
});
});
```

Comment: Regarding your `a:focus { outline: none; }` rule: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F78.html

Comment: Which IE version ? , it seems be a problem loading jquery on the FIDDLE (IE11) 

try this:
 
http://jsfiddle.net/hLkkzbqq/4/

Comment: check for browser compatibility. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions#Browser_compatibility
transition-duration is supported on IE10 and above browsers

Answer (score 0):

Using this [converter](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/), we get this code:

```
        #transformedObject {
         width:             220px;
         height:            70px;

         -moz-transform:    translateX(-330px);
         -o-transform:      translateX(-330px);
         -webkit-transform: translateX(-330px);
         transform:         translateX(-330px);
    }   

    /*
     * The following two rules are for IE only and
     * should be wrapped in conditional comments.
     * The -ms-filter rule should be on one line 
     * and always *before* the filter rule if
     * used in the same rule.
     */

    #transformedObject {

       /* IE8+ - must be on one line, unfortunately */ 
       -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1, SizingMethod='auto expand')";

       /* IE6 and 7 */ 
       filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(
                M11=1,
                M12=0,
                M21=0,
                M22=1,
                SizingMethod='auto expand');


       /*
        * To make the transform-origin be the middle of
        * the object.    Note: These numbers
        * are approximations.  For more accurate results,
        * use Internet Explorer with this tool.
        */
       margin-left: -387px; 
       margin-top: -3px;

    }
```

The above will get the CSS3 Transform working in IE and we can tweak this as we see fit.